# Use a date based on field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find a way to relate two sets of orders. Essentially, and inbound versus outbound analysis for a report. A load balance to see when I need to organize more pickups or deliveries.

I need to pull the delivery_date when billing_group = 3
I need to pull the origin_date when billing_group = 4

Hope this made some sense. Thank you all!

```
select convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Delivery_Date',
   convert(varchar,Origin_Date,101) as 'Origin_Date',
   sum(case when billing_group = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA',
   sum(case when billing_group = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR',
   count(*) as Total_Orders
from orders 
where Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and 
billing_group in ('3','4') 
group by Date
order by date desc
```

[image: Results I am looking for]

Would it be possible to combine these two separate queries into one to provide a the following columns?    date, OR to WA, and WA to OR  (like in the example above) where the date (regardless of origin or delivery date is used

```
    select convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Date',
    sum(case when billing_group = '3' and delivery_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA'
from orders 
where delivery_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 20, 0) and billing_group in ('3') 
group by delivery_date
order by date desc


select convert(varchar,Origin_Date,101) as 'Date',
        sum(case when billing_group = '4' and origin_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR'
    from orders 
    where origin_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 20, 0) and billing_group in ('4') 
    group by origin_Date
    order by date desc
```

Comment: What's your expect result and dbms?

Comment: given the convert command, it should be SQl Server @D-Shih

Comment: Sample data would go a long way here. Check out the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group by `convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101)` instead of `date`.

When you use aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate colunms in `group by`.

```
select convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Delivery_Date',
   sum(case when billing_group = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA',
   sum(case when billing_group = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR',
   count(*) as Total_Orders
from orders 
where Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and 
billing_group in ('3','4') 
group by convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101)
order by date  desc
```

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question, you can try to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Date',
           sum(case when billing_group = '3' and delivery_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA'
    from orders 
    where delivery_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 20, 0) and billing_group in ('3') 
    group by delivery_date
    UNION ALL
    select convert(varchar,Origin_Date,101) as 'Date',
           sum(case when billing_group = '4' and origin_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR'
    from orders 
    where origin_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 20, 0) and billing_group in ('4') 
    group by origin_Date
) t1
ORDER BY Date desc
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  
I am more concerned about calculating a count of orders where the delivery date is taken into consideration when billing_group 3 and a count of orders where the pickup date is taken into consideration when billing_group 4 and compare those two dates together

Oct 30      5  (shpt del billing group 3)    4 (shpt pu billing group 4)

Comment: @Thomas if this helped solve your problem you should mark it as accepted. Click on the left side V icon to do so.

Comment: @Thomas I saw you edit your question,  you can try my edit answer

Comment: That is definitely along the right track and thank you for that. What I would like to do, is to have the values from billing_group 3, and the values from billing_group 4 beside each other based on the date (one based on delivery and one based on pickup)

Comment: Could you provide us your expect result from your sample data? That really help